# Idiomatic usage of EitherT and errors

Tags: haskell

I have written the following code to replace the error message I get from `readFile`:

```
module Main where

import Control.Error
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL

replaceLeftT :: Monad m => String -> EitherT String m a -> EitherT String m a
replaceLeftT message e = EitherT $ do
  unwrapped <- runEitherT e
  let x = case unwrapped of
            Left _ -> Left message
            y      -> y
  return x

main :: IO ()
main = runScript $ do
  contents <- replaceLeftT "Could not read file" $
                scriptIO $ BSL.readFile "somefile"
  scriptIO $ putStrLn "Won't get here"
```

It feels clunky to me, like I'm missing a fundamental concept. Probably because I derived this function mostly by trial and error...

Any suggestions for a way to do this using existing `Control.Error` primitives, or monad primitives in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve that:

1. Using [hushT](http://beta.hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-1.4.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v%3ahushT) and [noteT](http://beta.hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-1.4.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v%3anoteT)

   You can overwrite the error message by first throwing it away (`hushT`) and then adding a new one (`noteT`).

   ```
   replaceLeftT :: Monad m => String -> EitherT String m a -> EitherT String m a
   replaceLeftT message = noteT message . hushT
   -- Same as: replaceLeftT message e = noteT message $ hushT e
   ```
2. Using [fmapLT](http://beta.hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-1.4.2/docs/Data-EitherR.html#v%3afmapLT)

   Another possibility is to use `fmapLT` to modify the message in the `Left`. For implementing `replaceLeftT`, we just always return the same new value, ignoring the old one:

   ```
   replaceLeftT :: Monad m => String -> EitherT String m a -> EitherT String m a
   replaceLeftT = fmapLT . const
   -- Same as: replaceLeftT message e = fmapLT (const message) e
   ```

Comment: `fmapLT` is the best way given the current API.  I've been considering adding a `(<??>)` operator for this purpose.

Comment: I was also able to implement a similar function with the same technique: `prefixNote = fmapL . (++)`